# Почему IIS Express отказывается работать в режиме отладки на 80 порту

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, iis-express

У меня стоит `OSPanel`, который выступает в роли базы данных *(удобный интерфейс `phpmyadmin` для работы с `MariaDB`)*. Сначала я отлаживал приложение на порту `5000`, но мне немного поднадоело постоянно вводить порт, и я решил сменить его на обычный для `http`:`80`. Перенастроил работу `OSPanel` *(он же в прошлом `Open Server`)*. И запустил отладку с помощью нажатия клавиш <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>. Но `IIS Express` тут же упал с ошибкой переполнения.

> Переполнение в результате выполнения арифметической операции.

Можно ли это дело подправить?

Comment: Из вопроса не понятна связь IIS и OSPanel: ни как было ранее, ни как именно перенастроили. Был IIS, к которому ходили напрямую, а потом стали ходить через Ospanel?

Comment: Нет, оспанель стоит только как бд, работает на 88 порту, но и с падает при настройке на 80 порт